# Searching for a value using Vlookup in Multi column

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am working on following data, where are need to merge Code and FName column from Left Hand side ex. HR_1Priya and look for an exact match by merging Columns from Right Hand Side.

I am using VLookup for this.

I tried this formula
`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A1,B1),$D$2:$E$5,1,FALSE)), "No", "Yes")`

This formula concatenates first two columns.

I don't understand how can i concatenate the columns from right hand side. i.e. ($D$2:$E$5) this part

[image: Example]

Comment: Add a column to the right side with a concatenation of the two columns. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please keep a column for concatenate values of the second set of values (Concatenate column D and E, say in column F) and then apply the same formula with a different range

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,B2),$F$2:$F$5,1,FALSE)), "No", "Yes")
```

By the way, value in A1 is Code and value in B1 is Fname. so you should rather start from A2 and B2.

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` does not allow "looking" in multiple columns columns *per se*.

However, there are a number of alternative methods.  The easiest is to add a ***"helper column"*** which concatenates the columns as necessary.

For example:

[image: screenshot]

Outside of that, you could use a set of **Array Formulas**.

- Microsoft.com : [How to use the INDEX and MATCH worksheet functions with multiple criteria in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/214142/how-to-use-the-index-and-match-worksheet-functions-with-multiple-crite)